# How to output number of occurrences of a positive negative number and Zero in Console Application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, console-application

I have a doubt on how to do this:
The user has to input 10 numbers, and the program has to output how many numbers are Positive, how many numbers are Negative, and how many are Zero, out of those 10 numbers. I remember getting it right once, but forgot the logic and so the code too. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone hlep me out by giving me the solution? Thanks!

Code:

```
Dim counter, pluscount, minuscount, zerocount As Decimal
    For counter = 1 To 10
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 numbers")
        counter = Console.ReadLine
        If counter > 0 Then
            pluscount = pluscount + 1
        ElseIf counter < 0 Then
            minuscount = minuscount + 1
        Else
            zerocount = zerocount + 1
        End If
        counter = counter + 1

        Console.WriteLine(pluscount & " number/s is/are positive.")
        Console.WriteLine(minuscount & " number/s is/are negative.")
        Console.WriteLine(zerocount & " number/s is/are zero")
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This code simply implements the solution submitted by @jmcilhinney with the addition of a ReadLine and a CDec. The correct answer is @jmcilhinney's

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Add a variable to hold user input
        Dim counter, input, pluscount, minuscount, zerocount As Decimal
        For counter = 1 To 10
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number")
            'do not change the value of counter in the loop
            'use a different variable to hold user input
            'Turn on Option Strict
            input = CDec(Console.ReadLine)
            If input > 0 Then
                pluscount = pluscount + 1
            ElseIf input < 0 Then
                minuscount = minuscount + 1
            Else
                zerocount = zerocount + 1
            End If
            'Do not increment the counter
            'Next increments the counter automaticly
            'counter = counter + 1
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(pluscount & " number/s is/are positive.")
        Console.WriteLine(minuscount & " number/s is/are negative.")
        Console.WriteLine(zerocount & " number/s is/are zero")
        'Stop the program from closing with a .ReadLine so you can see your results
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for that too, Mary [the frog! Ha Ha, LOL! no offence].

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're using `counter`. It is the loop counter and thus should be nothing else. Don't assign anything to it in the loop and don't increment it manually. When you call `ReadLine`, you need some other variable to assign the result to.

Also, there's no array there. Your loop counter should go from 0 to 9 and that should be the index into the array when you set an element.

Finally, don't tell the user to enter 10 numbers inside the loop. If you do that, you'll be teeming then to enter 10 numbers 10 times.

Comment: Sorry Prakash, but this doesn't seem to work either. Look:

Comment: Sorry Prakash, but this doesn't seem to work either. Look:
    Enter a number
    2
 Enter a number
    1
 Enter a number
    3
 Enter a number
    4
 Enter a number
    5
 Enter a number
    6
 Enter a number
    7
 Enter a number
    8
 Enter a number
    -9
 Enter a number
    0
    

and then it gives the wrong number of occurrences!

Comment: Please, somebody. I would appreciate it if you could give the solution as soon as possible, because my Computer Exam is day-after tomorrow, and there will be practicals revolving around these concepts. Plus, this is the Final Exam. I will have to know it, to pass the exam. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I take back the bit about the array. I think I must have confused this question with another I had open at the time.

Comment: So, which part is confusing you? I told you to declare a variable, set that variable instead of `counter` and don't increment `counter`. Which of those three things can you not do?

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Findout the Count Right...Then You Have to Mention that Console.Writeline after Completing the For Loop Like This..

```
 Dim counter, pluscount, minuscount, zerocount As Decimal
 For counter = 1 To 10
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 numbers")
    counter = Console.ReadLine
    If counter > 0 Then
        pluscount = pluscount + 1
    ElseIf counter < 0 Then
        minuscount = minuscount + 1
    Else
        zerocount = zerocount + 1
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Next
    Console.WriteLine(pluscount & " number/s is/are positive.")
    Console.WriteLine(minuscount & " number/s is/are negative.")
    Console.WriteLine(zerocount & " number/s is/are zero")
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to take user input in an array. This array will have 10 elements which will be input by the user.
After the user has finished the input, you loop over the array and find which of the numbers entered are positive, negative or zero.
So in short, you need one array with 10 elements, 1 counter for the loop and 3 variables to hold the number of positive, negative or zero numbers entered.

Comment: You need to respond with code, not just a description. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Please read that - you're costing me rep because I have to downvote all of your bad responses.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, thanks for the tip. I appreciate you helping me in answering as I am new but I would appreciate it more if you would have just pointed out what I am doing wrong rather than downvote all my responses.

Comment: I haven't down-voted everything. As a matter of fact, the down-vote here is not mine.